# Spring Integration SFTP Exception Handling

Tags: spring-integration

I am converting each incoming message to a file and uploading to SFTP server.
I get huge exception stack trace logs when SFTP is not available during file upload. This happens every incoming message. Just wondering is there any cleaner solution, where I can catch these exceptions and log a  custom message using my CONFIGURED LOGGER ?

```
   <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${ftp.host}"></property>
        <property name="port" value="22" />
        <property name="user" value="${ftp.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${ftp.password}"></property>
        <property name="timeout" value="2000"></property>
    </bean>

    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="sftpChannel"></int:publish-subscribe-channel>
    <sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter" auto-create-directory="true" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" channel="sftpChannel" charset="UTF-8" remote-directory="${ftp.path}" remote-filename-generator-expression="headers[fileName] + '.xml'">
        <sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
            </bean>
        </sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I have modified the config as below :

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="sftpChannel"></int:publish-subscribe-channel>
<sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter" auto-create-directory="true" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" channel="sftpChannel" charset="UTF-8" remote-directory="${spectrum.ftp.path}" remote-filename-generator-expression="headers[fileName] + '.xml'">
    <sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
            <property name="failureChannel" ref="errorChannel" />
        </bean>
    </sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I send this file using :

```
    outputChannel = context.getBean("sftpChannel", org.springframework.integration.MessageChannel.class);
line#120->     if (outputChannel.send(payload)) {
                        ptsoLog.info("Successfully uploaded file : " + fileName + ".xml");
                    }else{
                        ptsoLog.error("File upload failed : " + e.getMessage());
                    }
```

but still get this exception :

```
    org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:306) ~[spring-integration-file-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:190) ~[spring-integration-file-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:182) ~[spring-integration-file-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:112) ~[spring-integration-file-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.execute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.doInvoke(ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:68) ~[spring-integration-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at $Proxy27.handleMessage(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:141) ~[spring-integration-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:123) ~[spring-integration-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178) ~[spring-integration-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149) ~[spring-integration-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at com.xx.xx.xxx.outputMessage(xxxOutputter.java:120) ~[src/:na]



        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
            at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:321) ~[spring-integration-sftp-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:295) ~[spring-integration-file-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
            ... 48 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
            at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:250) ~[spring-integration-sftp-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:316) ~[spring-integration-sftp-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
            ... 49 common frames omitted
        Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established
            at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:394) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:na]
            at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:na]
            at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:241) ~[spring-integration-sftp-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
            ... 50 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:321) ~[spring-integration-sftp-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:295) ~[spring-integration-file-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:250) ~[spring-integration-sftp-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:316) ~[spring-integration-sftp-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:394) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:241) ~[spring-integration-sftp-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, you can specify the second `onFailureExpression` option alongside with `failureChannel` to send an `ErrorMessage` with the `Exception` to another channel and do some transformation and logging in that flow.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for so wide info around an issue.

So, as we see by the StackTrace the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` is there too.

And what I can say by source code of it, that it sends an `ErrorMessage` to the `failureChannel` only if you specify `onFailureExpression`. (`#root`) should be enough for you.

And there is one more option - `trapException = true` if you want to suppress that exception for rethrowing to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still doen't work with following config.
    `<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="errorLogger" method="logError" />
    <bean id="errorLogger" class="com.smarttrade.posttrade.ErrorLogger" />`

Comment: I always get this exception in my log. I would like to supress this exception, as this IllegalStateException damanging my whole work flow of my system. 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
 at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:250) ~[spring-integration-sftp-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:316) ~[spring- 
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established

Comment: Great! Share, please, more StackTrace to your question and we'll see how to help you. From other side: do you mean that exception isn't thrown to the `failureChannel`?

Comment: Thats right. I have added modified config and stacktrace to my question. Please, have a look.

Comment: Yeah.. Not enough StackTrace. I need to see the point from `FileTransferringMessageHandler` to understand why `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` doesn't catch that `JSchException`

Comment: I have added the calling code and full stacktrace. please check.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I try your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked well with  `<property name="trapException" value="true" />`